# Is CGColorSpaceRef not an AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, segmentation-fault, core-image

Xcode 7.0 complains about my Swift statement:

```
let options : [String : AnyObject] = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : true]
```

*(options is used a parameter of a Core Image CIContext object initialization)*

and shows the error message: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

When i change the code to

```
let options : [String : AnyObject] = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() as CGColorSpace?, kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : true]
```

The error message is gone but Xcode is still in trouble and shows now a compiler error: "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11".

So, how can i write the statement correctly in Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unwrap `CGColorSpace`. Here is the **safe** working example:

```
var options = [String: AnyObject]()

if let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() {
    options = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: colorspace]
}

let context = CIContext(options: options)
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Or with options as a constant: `let space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let options : [String: AnyObject] = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : space!]`

Comment: is there another safe way with options as a constant? (i'm beginner in Swift ...)

Comment: @markus7335 you should always keep in mind that if that color space is declared optional by Apple, it may return nil in some circumstances, and forcibly unwrapping it would crash the entire app.